# Приоритеты не соблюдаются. Почему постфиксный инкремент (a++) выполняется после префиксного (++a)?

Tags: javascript, инкремент

Всем привет! Небольшие непонятки по приоритетам между i++ и ++i. Согласно информации с сайта https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence у постфиксного инкремента приоритет выше над префиксным. Но по моему примеру не сходится:

```js
var a = 1;
a = ++a + a++ * a
/*2 + 2 * 3 = 8 - как считает интерпретатор, т.е. префикс выполнил раньше постфикса, даже несмотря на то что у него приоритет ниже*/
/*3 + 1 * 3 = 6 - как я считаю исходя из приоритетности пост- и префиксных инкрементов*/
console.log(a);
```

В чем тут подвох?

```js
var a = 1;
console.log(++a - a++);// Возвращает 0, хотя исходя из приоритетов должно быть 2(если соблюдены приоритеты).
```

Собственно почему не соблюдаются приоритеты согласно таблицы?

Comment: ты неправильно считаешь :-)

Comment: слагаемое (операнд) `++a` идет раньше, чем `a++`

Comment: А зачем такой код писать? (мне просто интересно, в чем необходимость).

Comment: А зачем такой код писать? (мне просто интересно, в чем необходимость).  учусь, вот столкнулся

Comment: Не нужно так писать. Это самое главное, что Вы должны вынести с этого.И это в js хорошо, а в с++ может быть все что угодно (ведь переставлять слагаемые нам никто не запрещает для простых типов).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё верно:

```
var a = 1;
// a = ++a + a++ * a
a = a + 1     // 2, первое слагаемое
var aprev = a // имитация постфикса
a = a + 1     // 
aprev * a     // 2 * 3, второе слагаемое
a = 2 + 2*3   // 8
```

Вы переоцениваете приоритеты, более высокий приоритет не значит, что все выражения с ним будут вычислены первыми.
Приоритеты - всего лишь как расстановка скобок: `a = (++a) + ((a++)* a)`.
Но вот это выражение(после расстановки приоритетов) выполняется слева-направо(таково свойство бинарных операторов типа `+`).

Comment: т.е. префикс выполнил раньше постфикса, даже несмотря на то что у него приоритет ниже?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что это унарные операторы? Я, честно говоря, не могу придумать пример, когда бы они конфликтовать, чтобы пришлось применить разность приоритетов. Это ссылочные операторы, тут `--a--` не напишешь.

Comment: Можно с унарным минусом: в выражении `-a++` постфиксный оператор применяется раньше. *Правда это никак не влияет на результат*

Comment: Т.е. приоритеты - всего лишь как расстановка скобок: `a = (++a) + ((a++)* a)`. Но вот это выражение(после расстановки приоритетов) выполняется слева-направо

Comment: Так мне стало понятно. Скажите пожалуйста, где можно научится нормально различать операторы и как они взаимодействуют. Трудно их воспринимаю.

Comment: Поначалу - в интерпретаторе. Проверять, если не понятно. Потом привыкнете) Лучше таки воздерживаться от нетривиальных конструкций. Они полезны разве что на собеседованиях)